# mybatis oracle procedure SYS_REFCURSOR setting parameter error

Tags: spring, mybatis

I am using spring 3 with Mybatis latest version.

I am trying to make procedure call which returns cursor result, following is my code

My Error is as following, any help is appreciated..

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may involve com.comcast.triage.dao.AccountDetailDao.getAccountDetail-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: { ? =          call ABC.get_acc_info(?, ?, ?, ?) }
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:364)
    at $Proxy21.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:250)
```

Following is dao interface

```
public interface AccountDetailDao {
    void getAccountDetail(Map<String, Object> parameter);
}
```

Following is my mapper xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.dao.AccountDetailDao">

<resultMap id="accountDetailResult" type="accountDetail">
    <result property="usid" column="usid" />
    <result property="accountNumber" column="account_number" />
    <result property="headendInEEg" column="headend_in_eeg" />
    <result property="customerType" column="customer_type" />
    <result property="corp" column="corp" />

</resultMap>

<update id="getAccountDetail" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
{ #{o_acc_cur,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} = 
    call ABC_TRI.get_acc_info(#{accountNumber,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{authGuid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{mac,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{usid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}) }
</update>
```

mybatis also contains config for alias

```
<typeAlias type="com.comcast.triage.domain.AccountDetail" alias="accountDetail"/>
```

following is my oracle package procedure signature

```
PROCEDURE get_acc_info( 
   i_account_number      IN  VARCHAR2,  
   i_auth_guid           IN  VARCHAR2,
   i_mac                 IN  VARCHAR2, 
   i_usid                IN  VARCHAR2,
   o_acc_cur             OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

Caller test is as following

```
@Autowired
```

private AccountDetailDao accountDetailDao;

@Test
public void test() {

```
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put("i_account_number", null);
param.put("i_auth_guid", null);
param.put("i_mac", "0162014707802#0");
param.put("i_usid", null);

accountDetailDao.getAccountDetail(param);

Object obj =param.get("o_acc_cur");

Assert.assertTrue(true);
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the stored procedure in database to make sure `o_acc_cur` is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry my bad.

this signature is for function which returns the cursor.

```
{ #{o_acc_cur,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} = 
    call ABC_TRI.get_acc_info(#{accountNumber,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{authGuid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{mac,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{usid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}) }
```

but i am using stored procedure so instead using return i tried following and it worked for me.

```
call UES_TRIAGE.get_acc_info(
        #{account_number,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},  
        #{auth_guid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, 
        #{mac,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, 
        #{usid,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
        #{accountDetails,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet}
        )
```